# How can I store different tuples in a list using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

My code is given below. What I want to accomplish is to add different arrays to my dictionary if score is higher or equals to the best score. For example: [(0.0001, 0.001, "linear"), (1.0, 1.0, "rbf")] etc.

```
C= [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01,0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
gamma=[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
kernel= ["linear","rbf"]
best_score = 0.0
best_C =0.0
best_gamma = 0.0
best_kernel = ""
parameters = {}

for i in C:
    for j in gamma:
        for k in kernel:
            clf = SVC(C=i, gamma=j, kernel=k)
            clf.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
            y_predict_train = clf.predict(X_train_std)
            score = accuracy_score(y_train, y_predict_train)
            if score >= best_score:
                parameters = i, j, k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `parameters = i, j, k` with `=` you are overwriting the `parameter` variable with something else, which in this case is the tuple `(i, j, k)`.

In order to add something to the dictionary you need to write

```py
parameters[some_key] = i, j, k
```

But you don't have a key and it seems what you really want is not a dictionary, but a `set` or a `list`.

Initialize parameters as `parameters = set()` and replace `parameters = i, j, k` with `parameters.add((i, j, k))`. If you prefer a list, initialize parameters as `parameters = []` and replace `parameters = i, j, k` with `parameters.appendi, j, k))`.